# Objective-c: Using custom types in protocol member declaration

Tags: objective-c

Please consider the following header (LessonDelegate.h):

```
#import "Lesson.h"

#ifndef BirdEye_LessonDelegate_h
#define BirdEye_LessonDelegate_h


@protocol LessonDelegate <NSObject>

- (BOOL) lesson:(Lesson*)lesson didRequestNavigation:(NSString*) url;

@end

#endif
```

It gives an error here:

- (BOOL) lesson:(**Lesson***)lesson didRequestNavigation:(NSString*) url;

saying "Expected a type". It complains about Lesson type even if it is declared and successfully used in other classes.

`Lesson.h` is where it is supposed to be (same folder) and looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleManifest.h"
#import "Activity.h"
#import "LessonDelegate.h"

@interface Lesson : Activity

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SimpleManifest *manifest;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) Activity *runningActivity;
@property (weak) id<LessonDelegate> delegate;

- (id) initWithUrl:(NSString*) aurl;
- (NSString*) deteails;

@end
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: instead of importing you can give `@class Lesson` deceleration in LessonDelegate.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### LessonDelegate.h

```
@class Lesson; // there was a missing ; here

@protocol LessonDelegate <NSObject>

- (BOOL) lesson:(Lesson*)lesson didRequestNavigation:(NSString*) url;

@end
```

#### Lesson.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleManifest.h"
#import "Activity.h"
#import "LessonDelegate.h"

@interface Lesson : Activity

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SimpleManifest *manifest;
@property (retain, nonatomic, readonly) Activity *runningActivity;
@property (weak) id<LessonDelegate> delegate;

- (id) initWithUrl:(NSString*) aurl;
- (NSString*) deteails;

@end
```

Comment: To explain a little. A protocol is really just a header that you adopt. So it works just like other headers. @class promises that you will define a class somewhere that is visible to your implementation file.